# How do i create unit test for a client service with void methods?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5, quarkus

I want to create a unit test for a client service.
The function of the client service is to call the webservice, get data, and update the database as scheduled.
The scheduled method return void.

How to create unit test for a

1. client service
2. schedule method
3. void returning methods

The client is like this:

```java
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class ClientClass {
    
      private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(VdsClient.class);
    
      @Inject
      Client client;
    
      VMR vmr;
    
      CommandService commandService;
    
      public VdsClient(VMR vmr,
          CommandService commandService) {
        this.vmr = vmr;
        this.commandService = commandService;
      }
    
      @Scheduled(XXX)
      public void getVal() {
        var monitoringStateFilter =
            new VMF.vmf(true, true);
        var monoResultList =
            vmr.fvms(monitoringStateFilter)
                                       .collectList();
        if (monoResultList != null) {
          var resultList = monoResultList.block();
          if (resultList != null) {
            resultList.stream()
                      .map(row -> row.getValue("val", val.class))
                      .map(vin -> this.updateEstimate(val.getValue()))
          }
        }
      }
      public Tuple2<String, Boolean> updateEstimate(String val) {
        List<route> routeList;
        try {
          routeList = vdsClient.getval(val)
                               .getItem();
          boolean hasDealerDestination = false;
          for (Route route : routeList) {
            if (vd.DestLocationType._00.value()
                                                .equals(route.getTransportConnectionPointTyp())) {
              hasDealerDestination = true;
              var estimate = DateTimeUtil.convertToInstantWithOffset(route.getArrivalDate(),
                  route.getArrivalTime(), route.getTimezone(), DateTimeUtil.PATTERN_LONG_DATE);
              if (estimate == null) {
                return Tuples.of(val, false);
              }
              var result = this.updateVehicleEstimate(val, estimate);
              return Tuples.of(val, result);
            }
          }
          if (!hasDealerDestination) {
            return Tuples.of(val, false);
          } else {
            return Tuples.of(val, false);
          }
        } catch (route e) {
          return Tuples.of(val, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return Tuples.of(val, false);
        }
      }
    
      public Boolean updateVehicleEstimate(String val, Instant estimate) {
        var vehicleUpdate = vu.vuc.builder()
          .val(new Val(val))
          .Estimate(estimate)
          .build();
        return (Boolean) cs.ec(vu).block();
      }
```

Comment: A unit test is really to confirm that the external effects of the unit happen as expected given certain inputs.  External effects can be return values, and modification of state.  So, given that you called the method, how do you ensure that the state modification happened?  What you need is either a mock/harness to represent the external service being invoked, and ensure that certain mutations did or did not happen as you expect.  Either mocking some part of your webservice client, or using something like wiremock to mock the external webservice might do.

Answer (score 1):

A unit should only be testing that a particular unit of code is working fine. In your case, for the unit test, you should assume that the webservice will return the data and the db updation works fine. We can accomplish this through mocking the response for each of these calls.

For void returning methods, you can actually verify if the call was indeed made or not.

For example:

```
Mockito.verify(mockedObject, Mockito.times(1)).callWebService(mockedParameter1, mockedParameter2);
```

There is another way, though I personally don't prefer that:
You can declare a class variable and make sure the value updates itself whenever the scheduled method reaches the end of the code. Read that value in your test and assert on its value. If the value is updated, then your code worked fine, else NO and it's a failure.

Also, in case you want to actually make sure the webservice returned the correct response / db entry was updated, then those should be part of integration tests and not unit tests.